# PowerShell : Import-Module : assembly name or codebase was invalid (HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Tags: powershell, nuget, bing, powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

I just installed the new [ISE Module Browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/02/23/ise-module-browser-a-new-way-to-manage-your-powershell-modules.aspx), wanted to try the first module, I've chosen the `Bing` module (which require another module called `BetterCredentials`, but that was handled well, so no problem).

So as mentioned in the beginning of the script of the Bing module, I had to do this :

[image]

and so did I, I registered and got my ApiKey, when trying to "`Import-Module`"
Bing, using that ApiKey, I get this "famous" error :

[image]

As far as I could see, there was no problem with the name of the module, what is the problem ? what should I do ?

**Update**

PowerShell however recognizes the cmdlets but can't execute them :

[image]